# Extracting value from excel without activating workbook

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am working from `MS Word` and need to extract data from `Excel Workbook` using following code:

It will `Find` TICKER in Workbook and if its found then it will set SECTOR variable using value from Workbook.

```
Set MyXL = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

If MyXL.ActiveWorkbook.NAME = "LIST.xlsm" Then
Set eXwb = GetObject("C:\Users\dell\Desktop\WEBD\LIST.xlsm")
Else
Set eXwb = MyXL.Workbooks("LIST.xlsm")
eXwb.Activate
End If

eXwb.Worksheets("Sheet4").Cells.Find(What:=TICKER).Offset(0, 2).Activate ' Is there any oneline code to find and set SECTOR variable without activating workbook
Set SECTOR = eXwb.Application.ActiveCell
```

Is there any possibility that I can extract data without activating eXwb workbook. 
Is there any one-line code to find and set SECTOR variable without activating workbook.

Comment: If your worksheet data are suitably structured, your can extract it via ADODB - without even having Excel installed. See: https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/import_excel_list_into_word_dropdownlist.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the line `eXwb.Activate`. Also remove `.Activate` from `eXwb.Worksheets("Sheet4").Cells.Find(What:=TICKER).Offset(0, 2).Activate` Directly work with the range

Your code can be written as

```
Set MyXL = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

If MyXL.ActiveWorkbook.Name = "LIST.xlsm" Then
    Set eXwb = GetObject("C:\Users\dell\Desktop\WEBD\LIST.xlsm")
Else
    Set eXwb = MyXL.Workbooks("LIST.xlsm")
End If

Dim SECTOR As Object '~~> Code is run from MS Word

Set SECTOR = eXwb.Worksheets("Sheet4").Cells.Find(What:=TICKER)

'~~> Check if .Find returned something
If Not SECTOR Is Nothing Then
    Set SECTOR = SECTOR.Offset(, 2)
    MsgBox SECTOR.Value
Else
    MsgBox "Ticker " & TICKER & " was not found"
End If
```

Comment: what is the meaning of run time `Error 13 type mismatch`? at `Set SECTOR = eXwb.Worksheets("Sheet4").Cells.Find(What:=TICKER).Offset(0, 2)` I manually checked and found Ticker is exist in workbook.

Comment: Did you define `SECTOR` as range? `Dim SECTOR As Range`

Comment: Sorry there is a small change. I have updated the post. you may have to refresh it to see it

Comment: what if `TICKER` actually don't exist in workbook? Does it tackle that too?

Comment: Yes.. `If Not SECTOR Is Nothing Then` checka if `.Find` returned something. You can add an `else` to that `If` if you want to do something for example let the user know that ticker was not found. I have updated the post to reflect that

Comment: I just want to know why my macro is working without adding `Dim SECTOR As Range` line to the main code? with that I am getting `Compiler error Method or data not found` at `.Offset`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186402/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-ibn-e-ashiq).